# Galois extension of local fields with a separable extension of residue fields of positive characteristic

Tags: commutative-algebra, galois-theory, local-field

I am reading the notes of a course on local fields, and I came accross the following statement that may be implicitly given at some point.

> Consider $L/K$ a finite Galois extension of local fields. Denote by $k_L$ and $k_K$ the respective associated residue fields. Assume that $k_K$ has prime characteristic $p>0$ and that the extension $k_L/k_K$ is separable. Then $k_L/k_K$ is actually Galois.

I really can't find out the reason what this extension of residue fields must be Galois in this case. Could someone give me a hint about it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since $L/K$ is Galois, $L$ is obtained by adjoining the roots of some polynomial $f \in \mathcal O_K[t]$ to $K$.   Then $k_L$ is obtained by adjoining the roots of the image $\overline{f} \in k_K[t]$ to $k_K$.  That makes $k_L$ a normal extension of $k_F$, hence Galois.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense to me. Thank you @D_S